# How to make dot matrix printer print every line of 'tail -f'

Tags: printing, tail, cups

I have a dot matrix printer, an Epson LQ-500.

It works well with CUPS, and I use it to print listings sometimes, text files, etc.

now, I'd like to use it as a logging printer. for that, I need it to print a line, when it is appended to a file or named pipe.

I was thinking about using something like this:

```
tail -n1 -f file | lpr -l -h -P Epson-LQ-500
```

but it doesn't work, the print job is constantly held.
Then I tried this:

```
tail -n1 -f file | lp -d Epson-LQ-500 -o raw -H immediate
```

and it doesn't work either, the print job is held indefinitely.

When using `tail` without `-f`, or when using `cat` it all works fine, but CUPS just won't let it print line-by-line.

So, how do I do that?

Comment: What an interesting idea... I feel like this must have been the way things were done at some point in time... so it must be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda worked around that problem with this:

```
tail -n2 -f file | while read line
do
echo $line | lpr -l -h -P Epson-LQ-500
done
```

but I'm not sure, whether this is best practice.

Answer (score 3):

The CUPS system is a printer *spooler* (i.e., it assumes that the printer is shared; it collects the stuff to be printed and sends it to the printer only when it is finished, in order not to delay other people's printouts when you send a page header, do 1/2 hour computing and then print the rest).

The easiest way around this would be to send the output directly to the printer device (that probably means first convincing CUPS that it should leave it alone, and making sure that the printer does understand the text sent to it).

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -f file > /dev/lp0
```

assuming a parallel printer and appropriate permissions, and you can't share the printer.

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n2 -f file | while read line
do
    echo $line | lpr -l -h -P Epson-LQ-500
done
```

Old-school line printers are great because of their immediacy; when a character gets dumped out */dev/lp0*, it goes right to unhackable paper.

If you were tailing this file to catch an intrusion (or a system crash), you've added the delay and insecurity of lines passing through more and more software steps - the shell, lpr, the printer's filters - before they get added to the page.

If the computer crashes or the power goes out or someone has hacked lpr, the printer doesn't get to log the event accurately.

For non-critical things, that's great if it provides other conveniences; I use old line printers to print labels one-at-a-time (laser printers require I print a whole sheet).

If it's time or security critical stuff that's going to the printer, use

```
tail -f file > /dev/lp0
```

(though if it's *really* critical info you need to log to paper, you could bypass the shell and filesystem altogether in the kernel.)

Old-school line printers don't need *any* drivers to print plain text in real time.